# Prime numbers, Hardy conjecture and Ulam spiral

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to know why if the Hardy Littlewood conjecture is true, this could explain the position of the prime numbers on the diagonal of Ulam spiral. Thanks.

Comment: The wiki on Ulam spiral mentions the connection. Did you read it?

Comment: I don't know what it would mean to "explain the position of the prime numbers on the diagonal of the Ulam spiral". Before a mathematical answer can be offered, the question has to be made more precise.